# Given binary tree represented as an array, find the pre-order traversal of it

Tags: algorithm, tree, traversal

Given a binary tree represented as the array [_,21,18,19,7,3,8,5,2,1]. What is the result of the pre-order traversal of this tree? The _ indicates an empty location in the array.

I'm confused by this because the tree can have more than one configuration, right? So, the pre-order traversals can be different. There is a "none of the above" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a binary tree represented as an array, `a`, typically the root is at `a[1]`. Given a node at position `x`, its left child is at `a[x*2]` and its right child is at `a[(x*2)+1]`. So the root's left child is at `a[2]` and its right child is at `a[3]`.

The left child of the node at `a[2]` is at `a[4]`, and the right child of the node at `a[3]` is at `a[7]`.

For a node at position `x`, its parent is at `a[x/2]`.

Given that, you should be able to construct your tree from that array. And then you can easily determine the preorder traversal.